# How to implement directions search between two locations for android google maps

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

I'm using PlaceAutocompleteFragment for current location and destination location. But I cant implement direction search like Uber. Anyone help me?

## My Code:

```
PlaceAutocompleteFragment originAutocomplete = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.origin_autocomplete_fragment);
    //AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder().setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_CITIES).build();
    //originAutocomplete.setFilter(typeFilter);
    originAutocomplete.setHint("Current Location");
    originAutocomplete.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Place selected: " + place.getName());
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            Log.d(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });



PlaceAutocompleteFragment destinationAutocomplete = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.destination_autocomplete_fragment);
destinationAutocomplete.setHint("Search Destination");
destinationAutocomplete.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Place selected: " + place.getName());
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            Log.d(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });
```

## But I want look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Screenshot:

## activity_main2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main2Activity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:hint="Enter Place Here"
        android:textColorHint="#BDBDBD"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        android:popupBackground="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:hint="Enter Place Here"
        android:textColorHint="#BDBDBD"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        android:popupBackground="@android:color/white"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

## Main2Activity:

```
package com.eride.rider;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.eride.rider.utility.PlaceArrayAdapter;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {

    private static final String TAG = "Main2Activity";
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    private static final int GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID = 0;
    private AutoCompleteTextView mAutocompleteTextView, mAutocompleteTextView2;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private PlaceArrayAdapter mPlaceArrayAdapter;
    private static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS_MOUNTAIN_VIEW = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(20.86382, 88.15638), new LatLng(26.33338, 92.30153));

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


        mAutocompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
        mAutocompleteTextView2 = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView2);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(Main2Activity.this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .enableAutoManage(this, GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID, this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .build();

        mPlaceArrayAdapter = new PlaceArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, BOUNDS_MOUNTAIN_VIEW, null);
        mAutocompleteTextView.setAdapter(mPlaceArrayAdapter);
        mAutocompleteTextView2.setAdapter(mPlaceArrayAdapter);

        //http://kvenkataprasad.blogspot.com/2017/03/autocomplete-google-places-api-example.html
        mAutocompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, String.valueOf(mPlaceArrayAdapter.getItem(position).placeId));
                placeResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull PlaceBuffer places) {
                        if (places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Address1: " + places.get(0).getAddress());
                            Log.d(TAG, "LatLng1: " + places.get(0).getLatLng().latitude +", "+ places.get(0).getLatLng().longitude);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        mAutocompleteTextView2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, String.valueOf(mPlaceArrayAdapter.getItem(position).placeId));
                placeResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull PlaceBuffer places) {
                        if (places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Address2: " + places.get(0).getAddress());
                            Log.d(TAG, "LatLng2: " + places.get(0).getLatLng().latitude +", "+ places.get(0).getLatLng().longitude);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }

    @Override public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(23.793740, 90.388078);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 16));
        addMapMarker(latLng);
        //locationButtonClicked();
    }

    private void addMapMarker(LatLng latLng) {
        mMap.clear();
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 16));
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        mPlaceArrayAdapter.setGoogleApiClient(mGoogleApiClient);
        Log.d(TAG, "Google Places API connected.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mPlaceArrayAdapter.setGoogleApiClient(null);
        Log.d(TAG, "Google Places API connection suspended.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Google Places API connection failed with error code: " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        Toast.makeText(this, "Google Places API connection failed with error code:" + connectionResult.getErrorCode(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

## PlaceArrayAdapter:

```
package com.eride.rider.utility;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompleteFilter;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePrediction;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePredictionBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class PlaceArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PlaceArrayAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete> implements Filterable {

    private static final String TAG = "PlaceArrayAdapter";
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private AutocompleteFilter mPlaceFilter;
    private LatLngBounds mBounds;
    private ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete> mResultList;


    public PlaceArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, LatLngBounds bounds, AutocompleteFilter filter) {
        super(context, resource);
        mBounds = bounds;
        mPlaceFilter = filter;
    }

    public void setGoogleApiClient(GoogleApiClient googleApiClient) {
        if (googleApiClient == null || !googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient = null;
        } else {
            mGoogleApiClient = googleApiClient;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mResultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public PlaceAutocomplete getItem(int position) {
        return mResultList.get(position);
    }


    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    mResultList = getPredictions(constraint);

                    if (mResultList != null) {
                        results.values = mResultList;
                        results.count = mResultList.size();
                    }
                }

                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    // The API returned at least one result, update the data.
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    // The API did not return any results, invalidate the data set.
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }


    private ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete> getPredictions(CharSequence constraint) {

        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {

            Log.i(TAG, "Executing autocomplete query for: " + constraint);

            PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> results = Places.GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, constraint.toString(), mBounds, mPlaceFilter);

            // Wait for predictions, set the timeout.
            AutocompletePredictionBuffer autocompletePredictions = results.await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            final Status status = autocompletePredictions.getStatus();
            if (!status.isSuccess()) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error: " + status.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e(TAG, "Error getting place predictions: " + status.toString());
                autocompletePredictions.release();
                return null;
            }

            Log.i(TAG, "Query completed. Received " + autocompletePredictions.getCount() + " predictions.");
            Iterator<AutocompletePrediction> iterator = autocompletePredictions.iterator();
            ArrayList resultList = new ArrayList<>(autocompletePredictions.getCount());
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                AutocompletePrediction prediction = iterator.next();
                resultList.add(new PlaceAutocomplete(prediction.getPlaceId(), prediction.getFullText(null)));
            }
            // Buffer release
            autocompletePredictions.release();
            return resultList;
        }

        Log.e(TAG, "Google API client is not connected.");
        return null;
    }

    public class PlaceAutocomplete {
        public CharSequence placeId;
        public CharSequence description;

        PlaceAutocomplete(CharSequence placeId, CharSequence description) {
            this.placeId = placeId;
            this.description = description;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return description.toString();
        }
    }

}
```